# reducer doesnt update the state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have simple flow in my app. After request is finished i'm calling an action with a payload:

```
export const setVoteFlagCurrentPoll = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: SET_VOTE_FLAG_CURRENT_POLL,
    payload: true
  })
}
```

Then in reducer im changing one variable in a poll object which looks like this:

```
{
  idsurvey: 10, 
  topic: "random poll question", 
  answers: Array(4), 
  voted: false
}
```

Reducer itself:

```
case SET_VOTE_FLAG_CURRENT_POLL:
      return {...state, pollData: {...state.pollData, voted: action.payload}};
```

My issue is that variable 'voted' is not chaning its value. Its still the same which is 'false'. Interesting thing is I can just log that recuder as: `console.log({...state, pollData: {...state.pollData, voted: action.payload}});` and it works.. its logging with voted as true. Why is this happening?

Comment: I know. I connected parent component and I was passing that prop (pollData) to a child and it wasn't rerendering.. Now I connected that child directly and it works now but tbh I dont know why ;/..EDIT: So.. It doesnt update in parent component with connect function but it does in child.. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. It seems like mapStateToProps function was badly written..

before (not working):

```
const = ({user}) => ({user}); // its returning whole user reducer
```

after (working now):

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    user: state.user //same as above (I didnt want to change the code in other components..)
    pollData: state.user.pollData //pulling pollData directly
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.